# React redux unable connect/bind actions in the same file with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, babeljs

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const closeModal = id => ({
    payload: {
        id
    },
    type: 'CLOSE_MODAL'
});

const cfgAction = (a, b, c) => ({
    payload: {
        a,
        b,
        c
    },
    type: 'CFG_ACTION'
});

class classA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.doAction = this.doAction.bind(this);
    }

    doAction() {
        this.refs['aaa'].doOnRefItem();
    }

    render() {
        const { modals, closeModal } = this.props;
        // ...
        const buttons = <div className="buttons">
            <a onClick={() => closeModal("...")}>THIS WORKS</a>
            <a onClick={this.doAction}>THIS WORKS</a>
        </div>;
        return <div>
            <classB ref={'aaa'} />
            <classB ref={'bbb'} />
            {buttons}
        </div>;
    }
}

class classB extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    doOnRefItem() {
        const { cfgAction } = this.props;
        cfgAction("xxx", 5, true); //! *ERROR cfgAction is not a function*
    }

    render() {
        // ...
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ modals }, ownProps) => (
    { modals }
);

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) =>
    bindActionCreators(
        {
            closeModal,
            cfgAction
        },
        dispatch
    );
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(classB);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(classA);
```

NB: all is in the same file (not the actions).
I don't know why I can't access to the props to the function.
A solution could be do another file with the classB but in that case doesn't work this.refs['aaa'].doOnRefItem(); because it can't find the function (but access to the element).
I wish understand in both cases why doesn't work and how fix it.
Thanks


**UPDATE 1** 
I did the following change getting the ref error:

```
class ClassA extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.doAction = this.doAction.bind(this);

        this.r1 = React.createRef();
        this.r2 = React.createRef();
    }

    doAction() {
        // ERROR TypeError: r1.current.doOnRefItem is not a function
        this.r1.current.doOnRefItem();
        this.rr.current.doOnRefItem();
    }

    render() {
        const { modals, closeModal } = this.props;
        // ...
        const buttons = <div className="buttons">
            <a onClick={() => closeModal("...")}>THIS WORKS</a>
            <a onClick={this.doAction}>THIS WORKS</a>
        </div>;
        return <div>
            <ConnectedClassB ref={this.r1} />
            <ConnectedClassB ref={this.r2} />
            {buttons}
        </div>;
    }
}

class ClassB extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    doOnRefItem() {
        // ...
    }

    render() {
        // ...
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ modals }, ownProps) => (
    { modals }
);

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) =>
    bindActionCreators(
        {
            closeModal,
            cfgAction
        },
        dispatch
    );
const ConnectedClassB = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ClassB);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ClassA);
```

ERROR TypeError: r1.current.doOnRefItem is not a function. Logging 'r1.current' I can see the class object...

**UPDATE 2** 
Fixed with the following change:

```
const ConnectedClassB = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { forwardRef: true })(ClassB);
```

Comment: I don't think you are creating the redux store to `mapStateToProps`. Please use `createStore` from `react-redux` package to do same

Comment: @Anuj yes I had created the store, middleware cfg etc in another file, the problem isn't the basic configuration of redux but this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least a couple issues immediately.

First, note that your React component names start with lower-case letters.  React components should *always* start with an upper-case letter, so that the JSX transform works correctly.  Change `classA` and `classB` to `ClassA` and `ClassB` everywhere you're using them.

Second, remember that `connect()` returns a new component type.  You are calling `connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(ClassB)`, but not using the returned component type anywhere - it's being thrown away.  Instead, you'd need:

```js
const ConnectedClassB = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(ClassB);
```

and then your `ClassA` component needs to actually render that connected component type:

```js
<ConnectedClassB />
```

In addition, React string refs are basically deprecated.  Use [object refs via `React.createRef()` instead](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs).

Finally, note that you should really be using [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) instead of the function form.

Comment: I did the edits as you can see in the 'UPDATE 1', but with the refs the problem persist... any suggestions? thanks

Comment: So the next question is, why are you trying to use refs to call methods in a child component? That's not the React way of doing things.

Comment: so how can I eadit the "Update 1" code for doing that in react way?